FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for roles with the SUPERUSER attribute
I keep getting this error in my pgadmin in my digital ocean managed db
connection failed: FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for roles with the SUPERUSER attribute

It seems these error derives because I have a lot of open connections to the database, as I look through my open connections in my digital ocean dashboard I see a multitude of connections to the same database, it seems that's the case because I keep pulling an starting new docker images of my backend in prod whenever I update the backend code. My CD pipeline triggers and pulls the new image with docker compose up --force-create. I have a hunch that it's because when I pull new images and call force-create on docker compose, ,it doesn't close the database connection of the old images?
Here's my CD pipeline trigger
name: Deploy prod stack to DigitalOcean
on:
create:
branches:
- release
push:
branches:
- release
pull_request:
branches:
- release
jobs:
deploy:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: Checking out the repository
uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Copy docker-compose-api.prod.yml over to the server
    uses: appleboy/scp-action@v0.1.7
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
      username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
      key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
      passphrase: ${{ secrets.PASSPHRASE }}
      source: "docker-compose-api.prod.yml"
      target: /home/${{ secrets.USERNAME }}

  - name: Run the docker-compose-api.prod.yml stack
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.6
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
      username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
      key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
      passphrase: ${{ secrets.PASSPHRASE }}
      script: |
        echo ${{ secrets.CR_PAT }} | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin
        export DATABASE_HOST=${{ secrets.DATABASE_HOST }}
        export DATABASE_PORT=${{ secrets.DATABASE_PORT }}
        export DATABASE_NAME=${{ secrets.SERVER_DATABASE_NAME }}
        export DATABASE_USERNAME=${{ secrets.DATABASE_USERNAME }}
        export DATABASE_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.DATABASE_PASSWORD }}
        export RABBITMQ_HOST=${{ secrets.RABBITMQ_HOST }}
        export RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${{ secrets.RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER }}
        export RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASSWORD }}
        export RABBITMQ_QUEUE=${{ secrets.RABBITMQ_QUEUE }}
        docker compose -f docker-compose-api.prod.yml pull
        docker compose -f docker-compose-api.prod.yml up -d --force-recreate

I'd like to mention as well when I run docker ps I only see my new containers running, old containers are closed. So I still fail to see why the database connection keeps open
Edit: In my docker compose, I'm using hibernate java in one server, and the other server, I'm using strapi
